# Dynamic display of shipping options based on customer address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I'm new to Magento and our website supports different custom shipping options, e.g. `within the hour`, `tonight`, `overnight`, etc.

What I want to do is if the customer is at a particular location, I have to disable certain shipping options.

E.g.

- Auckland (`within the hour`, `tonight` and `overnight`) are available.
- Wellington (`overnight`) is available.

Thanks in advance